# Assigning Scripts to Variables for a Wrapper Script

Tags: bash, variables, sh, filenames, word-wrap

I am trying to assign bash scripts to variables for use in a wrapper script, yet every method I have tried has resulted to a "No such file or directory" error:

```
#!/bin/bash 
textgen=$(< textcreator.sh)
tablegen=$(< tablecreator.sh)
htmlgen=$(< webcreator.sh)


 exec $textproces
 if [[ $textproces -eq 0 ]]
    then
        echo "Text Processing has ran successfully"
        exec $listgen
        if [[ $listgen -eq 0 ]]
          then
              echo "List Generation has ran successfully"
              exec $pagegen
              if [[ $pagegen -eq 0 ]]
                then
                    echo "HTML Page Generation has ran successfully"
                    echo "The command wrapper has finished successfully"
                    exit 0
                else
                  echo "Error: HTML Page Generation was unsuccessful"
                  exit 1
              fi
          else
             echo "Error: Text Processing was unsuccessful"
             exit 1
        fi
    else
        echo "Error: Text Processing was unsuccessful"
        exit 1
 fi
```

The methods I have tried: cat filename, export, source and standard assigning. The idea is that it is to work without having to give a path name, all of these shells are in the same directory anyway. All help is vastly appreciated!

NOTE: I know its horrifying, but it was the way I thought of doing it with the IF statements

Comment: `wrapper script`. Can you show the workflow? How is the wrapper script called? From where? Using what? How do you run this? Using what command? And why your variables are not quoted and ,more concerning, why do you use exec(!)? Show an example, an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with all the relevant information, so I can reproduce an issue for example on [external sites](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php).

Comment: I have made the changes now. The wrapper script is called from either 'bash runsystem' or './runsystem'. It is called from a directory in my user files, all the scripts it uses are in that directory as well. They're not quoted as I assumed you wouldn't quote the filename as I have seen that before. I assumed exec would be suitable as I was not sure how to run a file with a variable name

Comment: What is the content of `$textproces` ? And why don't you quote it? Running it with exec is extremely dangerous. What are you trying to achieve? Why using `source` or `.` is not suited for you? You don't quote filenames, you should quote the content of the files when running with exec, unless you quote the files content (I think you don't). And what is `[[ $textproces -eq 0 ]]` supposed to do? Textprocess is text, moreover it's not quoted, is it modified inside `exec` call? If it contains any whitespace character, the syntax is just invalid. I think you mean `if (( $? == 0 ))` or similar

Comment: Ok, so let's keep that aside, and concentrate on the goal. You want to have a script called `textcreator.sh` with the content `a=1;` and you want to see the variable `a` being set in your `runsystem` script, right? Would that be an MCVE for your case?

Comment: Forgive me for asking a stupid question, but why are you assigning the entire text of the scripts to the variables instead of just the script names?

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several serious problems in the code.

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends upon which directory you were in when you executed the root script. So them being in the same directory does not help. You can `cd` into the directory containing the sub scripts before executing them from the root script.

Comment: I'm confused in what you mean by this. The root shell and sub shells are all in the same directory and the root shell is also ran on the same directory, is this what you mean?

Comment: A `shell` is not the same thing as a `script`. Each process ( or a script in execution ) has a `current working directory`. Its this directory that the program will look for if you reference any other script.

Comment: I'm understanding what you mean now, so I checked each scripts working directory but they are all in the same one. Thank you for the suggestion though, I can see why that would be an issue

Answer (score 0):

There are several serious problems with the code in the question.  Some are identified by [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/).  Always run Shellcheck on new and modified code.

Problems include:

1. The variables assigned at the start are not the variables that are used later.
2. The variables are set to the contents of the programs, not the names of the files containing the programs.  (The only way to use the contents would be to pass them to `eval`.  That would **not** be a good idea.)
3. `exec` is used to try to run the programs.  `exec` replaces the current program with a new program, determined by its arguments.  It's roughly equivalent to running another program and exiting immediately afterwards.  Once `exec` has been used, no code after it in the program is executed.
4. The paths to the programs to be run are not specified.  Since the programs are in the current directory (`.`), and `.` is usually not in the `PATH` (for very good reasons), the shell will issue 'command not found` errors for the attempts to run them.
5. The code tries to get the exit status of programs by checking the value of the variable containing the program name.  The exit status of a program can be obtained via the `$?` built-in variable.  However, the simplest way to check if a command failed is to use it directly in an `if`.

The [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code below attempts to fix the problems.  It also eliminates the nested `if` statements in an attempt to make the code clearer.

```
#!/bin/bash

textgen=textcreator.sh
listgen=tablecreator.sh
pagegen=webcreator.sh

if ! "./$textgen" ; then
    echo "Error: Text Processing was unsuccessful"
    exit 1
fi

echo "Text Processing has ran successfully"

if ! "./$listgen" ; then
    echo "Error: List Generation was unsuccessful"
    exit 1
fi

echo "List Generation has ran successfully"

if ! "./$pagegen" ; then
    echo "Error: HTML Page Generation was unsuccessful"
    exit 1
fi

echo "HTML Page Generation has ran successfully"
echo "The command wrapper has finished successfully"

exit 0
```

The code could be used in various other ways (e.g. send  error output to standard eror (`... >&2`), reduce duplication by using a function to output the error message and exit the program).